# Model Binder null on List<object> sometimes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding

I have a view model,and one of the properties of the view model is a an object called Profile. One of the properties of Profile is a list of another object, called CD. From the view, I set the POST body values to the following

`Profile.CD[0].Prop1=TEST&Profile.CD[0].Prop2=TEST&Profile.CD[1].Prop1=TEST2&Profile.CD[1].Prop2=TEST2`

If I were to add a third object to the list in the view, which would get posted as `Profile.CD[2].Prop1=TEST3` , in the controller all of the sudden `Profile.CD` is null. 2 items and below `Profile.CD` gets the values I would expect. As soon as I add in that third item the model binder stops working. I'm at my wits end, and I've tried everything I can think of.

Things I've tried

- Removing an item from the view, and adding a new -- WORKS
- Removing both from the view, and adding 2 new items -- WORKS
- Adding a third item in the view -- FAILS `Profile.CD` is null in the view model

I'm not using any model state validation rules. When debugging, I've tried something like the following in the immediate window `?Request.Form.Where(x => x.Keys.Contain("Profile.CD")).ToList())` and sure enough, all of my values are present in the `Request` object even though the list is null in the view model.

The values of the objects in `Profile.CD` do not have to be unique.. I've tried setting every single value to "TEST" just to verify it's not the input causing this problem.

I'm truly lost..

**View Model**

```
public class PortalViewModel {
     public ProfileModel Profile { get; set; }
}
```

**Profile Model**

```
public class ProfileModel {
    //bunch of other static properties that are bound just fine.. like strings and decimals... 

    public List<CDModel> CD { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit (PortalViewModel Model)
{
    Repo.UpdateProfile(Model.Profile); // in this method it foreachs Profile.CD , but sometimes this is null and other times it get's it's values....

    return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not been able to find a coding solution to this problem, and started exploring other avenues. I have *fixed* the problem, but it makes very little sense.

I upgraded the project from .net core 1.0.1 to .net core 1.0.5 , and everything is working 100% of the time. In this upgrade, I made no code changes what so ever. Just upgraded .net core. Very very odd..